# Ошибка 2 error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1

Tags: c++, ооп

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
struct Train
{
    string final_destination;
    int number_train;
    int t_hour;
    int t_minute;
};
template<typename T>
class Tmain
{
protected:
    T*mas;
    int n;
public:
    Tmain()
    {
        mas = NULL;
        n = 0;
    }
    Tmain(int n)
    {
        this->n = n;
        mas = NULL;
    }
    Tmain(const Tmain& obj)
    {
        if (this == &obj)return;
        n = obj.n;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            mas[i] = obj.mas[i];
    }
    virtual ~Tmain()
    {
        if (mas) delete[]mas;
        mas = NULL;
        n = 0;
    }
    virtual void set() = 0;
    virtual void get() = 0;
};
istream&operator>>(istream& in, Train& train);
ostream&operator<<(ostream& out, const Train& train)
{
    out << "Final destination: " << train.final_destination << endl;
    out << "Number of train: " << train.number_train << endl;
    out << "Time: " << train.t_hour << ":" << train.t_minute << endl;
    return out;
}
class TTrain :public Tmain<Train>
{
public:
    TTrain() :Tmain<Train>(){};
    TTrain(int n) :Tmain<Train>(n){};
    TTrain(const TTrain& obj) :Tmain<Train>(obj){};
    void set() override
    {
        cout << "Input info for " << n << " trains" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            cin >> mas[i];
    }
    void get() override
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << "Train #" << i << endl;
            cout << mas[i];
        }
    }
    void addTrain(string final_destination, int number_train, int t_hour, int t_minute)
    {
        Train *arr = new Train[n + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            arr[i] = mas[i];
        arr[n].final_destination = final_destination;
        arr[n].number_train = number_train;
        arr[n].t_hour = t_hour;
        arr[n].t_minute = t_minute;
        delete[]mas;
        mas = arr;
        n++;
    }
    void getTrains(int t_hour, int t_minute)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (mas[i].t_hour > t_hour || (mas[i].t_hour == t_hour && mas[i].t_minute>t_minute))
            {
                cout << "Train #" << i << endl;
                cout << mas[i];
            }
            else cout << "Not found!" << endl;
        }
    }
    void getTrains()
    {
        int t_hour, t_minute;
        cout << "Enter time: " << endl;
        cin >> t_hour;
        cin >> t_minute;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (mas[i].t_hour > t_hour || (mas[i].t_hour == t_hour && mas[i].t_minute>t_minute))
            {
                cout << "Train #" << i << endl;
                cout << mas[i];
            }
            else cout << "Not found!" << endl;
        }
    }
};
istream&operator>>(istream& in, TTrain& train)
{
    string final_destination, number_train, t_hour, t_minute;
    cout << "Enter final destination: " << endl;
    getline(in, final_destination);
    cout << "Enter number of train: " << endl;
    getline(in, number_train);
    cout << "Enter time: " << endl;
    getline(in, t_hour);
    getline(in, t_minute);
    train.addTrain(final_destination, atoi(number_train.c_str()), atoi(t_hour.c_str()), atoi(t_hour.c_str()));
    return in;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter quentity trains: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    TTrain train(n);
    train.set();
    train.get();
    train.getTrains();
    train.getTrains(15, 45);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: не код а какая-то мешанина: вы даже сами запутались в названиях ваших типов, спутав `Train` и `TTrain`. Чтобы такого не происходило: старайтесь давать осмысленные имена типам и объектам, а также объявление и реализацию разностись в пространстве - желательно по разным файлам, объявление в хэдэр, а реализацию в файл .cpp

Answer (score 1):

Объявили

```
istream&operator>>(istream& in, Train& train);
```

реализовали

```
istream&operator>>(istream& in, TTrain& train)
```

Использовали в

```
cin >> mas[i]
```

первый - без реализации...